# How to connect over VNC to server ILO Remote Console?

Tags: vnc

I have HP server in my house, in garage.
I have connected to that server one LAN cable and one LAN cable to ILO port.
I can successfully open ILO over browser but cannot connect over remote console in browser.

In ILO management:
When I try to connect over "Intergrated Remote Console" i get this error: Microsoft Internet Explorer is required to run Integrated Remote Console.
Tried over IE, without success.

When I try over "Remote Console" I get blank screen:
[image]

And when I tried over IE "Remote Console" I get this error:
[image]

So I have enabled VNC to connect over VNC viewer on my Mac but also without success, it is connecting till the timeout (for about 2 minutes).
Tried telnet port 3389 and it is working.
[image]

Is there way to connect to ILO2 console?

Server: HP ProLiant DL380 G6

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't really about VNC... You just want to get the ILO console working.

- [Upgrade the firmware](http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=3884088&swItemId=MTX_7ac39b5ebc59499da055856d52&swEnvOid=4064) of the ILO to current.
- If you're using a Windows computer, choose the .NET Integrated Remote Console.
- If you're using a Mac, download Java and use the Java-based console.
- If you don't upgrade your firmware and are using IE you'll need to go to the IE settings and enable ***Compatibility View***, then refresh the page.

Comment: I just want to describe whole problem and I thought my solution is VNC. Used IE and Compatibility View but without success.

Comment: cannot download new firmare, it is asking login and I cannot regiter because I don't have HP sponsor: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmk3njqtll3op53/Screenshot%202017-04-26%2013.54.43.png?dl=0

Comment: A login is not required to obtain ILO firmware. The Windows firmware [for your ILO2 is located here](http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=3884088&swItemId=MTX_7ac39b5ebc59499da055856d52&swEnvOid=4064).

Comment: clicked on download link in ILO interface and has redirected me here :) tnx

Comment: why it says Windows firmware?

Comment: I have installed on that server Ubuntu server 16.04. and I'm connecting to ILO interface from my MAC and Windows.

Comment: Download the firmware to a Windows computer and extract the package. Upload the firmware to the ILO using the web interface.

Comment: upgraded firmware and I can login over IE on Windows. Thank you. It would be great if I could connect over VNC or Firefox on my MAC because now I have to start VM Windows on MAC to open over IE :)

Comment: You can use the Java console with a Mac.

Comment: how to open java console on mac and then connect?

Comment: The free support stops here :) You will have to figure that out. Try Safari or Firefox on Mac.